# How to fix text highlighting in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Some recent Chrome update changed a setting, and now it is impossible to select text in console.

Every time you press any output, it highlights the whole block, which won't show you highlighting a word!

This is happening when all you want to do it copy and paste `frank`

[image: chrome highlight block]

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can copy and paste out of the console like it used to work by just highlighting the word?!?

[image]

Chrome is up-to-date: Version 119.0.6045.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I am using macOS and I can click and select `frank` to copy it. Are you using Windows or Linux? If you think it's a bug then can you please file a bug report: https://crbug.com/ ?

Comment: Tested on Both Mac and Windows, It is related to the latest update.

Comment: Bug submitted: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1500369

Comment: Fixed! in Version 119.0.6045.160 (Official Build) (64-bit)